# replace regex capture a text without excepted string

Tags: .net, regex, powershell, replace

I have a problem. i'm programing a ansi to utf-8 format converter for php, css, js files and using windows10 powershell script console. please see my example code:

```
$replacer ="function( testing regex function( bla bla newfunction( alternative function ( not capture this mb_function( or mb_function ( need a right regex."
$regx = "([^_]function\s?\()+"
$replacer -replace $regx, "hot_function("
```

output(not valid) :

```
function( testing regexhot_function( bla bla nehot_function( alternativehot_function( not capture this mb_function( or mb_function ( need a right regex.
```

need valid output :

```
hot_function( testing regex hot_function( bla bla newhot_function( alternative hot_function( not capture this mb_function( or mb_function ( need a right regex.
```

i'm testing regex this page not found right syntax : https://regex101.com/r/kV4gV6/1 how to fix this problem please help me. Thank you all helpers.

Comment: **Regex101 does not support .NET regex.** It can be used to test simple patterns, but do not rely on it completely. You just need [`(?<!_)function\s*\(`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=\(%3f%3c!_\)function%5cs*%5c\(&i=function\(+testing+regex+function\(+bla+bla+newfunction\(+alternative+function+\(+not+capture+this+mb_function\(+or+mb_function+\(+need+a+right+regex.+need+only+capture+%22function\(%22+or+%22function+\(%22+and+not+start+mb_+ex%3a+mb_function\(+how+to+fix+%3f+im+using+regex+in+windows10+powershell+command+line+replace+function.&r=hot_function\().

Comment: Well, this simple lookbehind will work well at regex101.com, too. For other cases, where you need .NET regex syntax check and explanation of each subpattern, use [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/expresso.htm) (it is free, just after 30 days they ask you to register it for free).

Comment: Why have you tagged with C# if you are using PowerShell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a negative lookbehind in this case:

```
(?<!_)function\s*\(
^^^^^^
```

It will fail the match if an `f` is preceded with `_`.

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C!_)function%5Cs%2A%5C(&i=function(%20testing%20regex%20function(%20bla%20bla%20newfunction(%20alternative%20function%20(%20not%20capture%20this%20mb_function(%20or%20mb_function%20(%20need%20a%20right%20regex.%20need%20only%20capture%20%22function(%22%20or%20%22function%20(%22%20and%20not%20start%20mb_%20ex%3A%20mb_function(%20how%20to%20fix%20%3F%20im%20using%20regex%20in%20windows10%20powershell%20command%20line%20replace%20function.&r=hot_function()

Replace with `hot_function(`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your interest. I was looking at had. 3rd time I've been researching the site coding experiments. You say that site to my favorites. I use to download the program was very functional. There are already difficulties in the regex. Thank you very much again. Respects. +1

Comment: There is another useful site to test .NET regex: [*RegexHero*](http://regexhero.net/tester). You can even benchmark your patterns for free there. And as for the pattern, you can read a lot about [*lookarounds* here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).